# API Gateway LogGroup duplicate and details are missing

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm struggling to set up logs in CloudWatch for my RestApi via cdk.

This is my code:

```
const logGroup = new LogGroup(this, `apiLogs`, {
        logGroupName: `apiLogs`,
        retention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK
});

const api = new apigw.RestApi(this, `apiName`, {
        // set up CORS            
        defaultCorsPreflightOptions: {
            statusCode: 200,
            allowMethods: ['OPTIONS', 'GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
            allowOrigins: apigw.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS
        },
        deploy: true,
        restApiName: `apiName`,
        deployOptions: {
            accessLogDestination: new apigw.LogGroupLogDestination(logGroup),
            loggingLevel: apigw.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
            dataTraceEnabled: true
        }}
);
```

In the console, the settings of the logs that I want are called "Log full request/responses data". which should be the part

```
deployOptions: {
            accessLogDestination: new apigw.LogGroupLogDestination(logGroup),
            loggingLevel: apigw.MethodLoggingLevel.INFO,
            dataTraceEnabled: true
        }
```

This setting works as I want as shown in the screenshot:
[image: CloudWatch Settings after deployment]

However if I now check CloudWatch after sending requests to the API, two logGroups are created and have logs:

1. The first is the LogGroup with the name `apiLogs` as defined in my code but the output of the logs are not as detailed as I want them as shown here:
   [image: Logs of apiLogs]
2. The second is a LogGroup with a default name including the id of the endpoint and the logs include the detailed information that I want as shown here:
   [image: Logs of default]

Why are there 2 separate logGroups created and why is `apiLogs` not showing the detailed logs?

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway’s produce 2 types of logs:

**execution logs**

**access logs**

For execution logs - no way to control this, it’s an AWS managed log group (similar to Lambda). You can only configure access log behaviour.